# Glassfish jersey client not accepting spring data Page object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, glassfish, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Hi i am using glassfish jersey client for my spring rest controller.One of the rest controller returns **org.springframework.data.domain.Page** but i am struggling to write a jersey client for that particular controller.
Please find the code sample below

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Controller**

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<Book>> getBooks(Pageable pageable) {
    final Page<Book> allBook = bookRepository.findAll(pageable);
    final ResponseEntity<Page<Book>> response = ResponseEntity.ok().body(allBook);
    return response;
}
```

**Client Code**

```
private Page<Book> getBook((JerseyWebTarget target){

try {
        response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        response.readEntity(Page.class); //Compilation error : T has incompatible bounds
    } catch (ProcessingException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

I am not sure how to read page object using Jersey client.Getting following error while reading object **response.readEntity(Page.class); //Compilation error : T has incompatible bounds:Equality constraints: Page upper bounds**

Any help or hint should be appreciable.

Comment: Why are you mixing Jersey with Spring? Based on the error, I think you should be looking at your Page class. You're using Spring's `ResponseEntity<T>` rather than a `Response` from Jersey and the error is complaining about the `T` which, in your case, is the `Page` class. I googled the error and it seems a lot of people are seeing similar things with Java 8 and not Java 7. Perhaps see if it will compile and run with Java 7.

Comment: @Mike thank you for your comments even I don't like it to mix jersey with spring but this is how my project is developed so I don't want to violate it. Also as you mentioned we are using Java 1.8 again no way to use Java 1.7. Do you know any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: For generics use `readEntity(new GenericType<Page<Book>>(){});`

Comment: Though it looks like you want to use `new GenericType<List<Book>>(){})`.